# look through a string skipping/ignoring a specific character

Tags: regex

i'm trying to wrap my head around this and all the examples on google and stackoverflow aren't helping me understand.

i have this string

`{{@test: mytest}}`
`{{@test mytest}}`

I want to capture `test` and `mytest` from both those examples. so if that occurs in my string both will return the same array sets.

this is what i have/am trying to so far

`/{{\s*@\s*(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*}}/`

this will work on the first example but will not on the second one.

so i thought maybe the answer would be to search trough the string skipping the `:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't clearly defined your criteria, but assuming that the texts you want to match may not contain whitespace, you can use this:

```
/{{\s*@\s*([^:\s]*)\s*:?\s*([^}\s]*)\s*}}/
```

- `[^:\s]*` matches a string that contains neither colons nor whitespace
- `[^}\s]*` matches a string that contains neither closing braces nor whitespace
- `:?` matches an optional colon

Comment: i added the `\s*` so that it would match if there was a space there or not (so i'm led to believe from my tests)

Comment: @Eli: Yes, that's perfectly OK, isn't it?

Comment: this works great! i changed it a bit because i was causing some results to be omitted. i made it into this `{{\s*@\s*([^:\s]*)\s*:?\s*(.*)\s*}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try `\{\{\s*@([^@:\s]+)\s*:?\s+([^}\s]+)\s*\}\}`.

**EDIT:** Ack, Tim Pietzcker beat me to it. There are some subtle differences between our expressions, but either one should do what you want, I think. I have chosen to use `+` rather than `*` in a few places, where my interpretation of your question led me to believe that there had to be at least one of a given character.

**EDIT 2:** One advantage of my approach would be that it does not match `{{@testmy-test}}`.